# Assignment Operation in Apex

Tags: apex, operators

I'm going through a code implemented by one of our vendors and come across below assignment operation,

```
serialNumberObj.Prefunded__c = snWrap.Prefunded == 'ZEW';
```

Here, Prefunded__c is a boolean field and Prefunded is a string variable in a wrapper class.

Can somebody explain me please, how above code segment works? And what is the role of == 'ZEW'? And what is the theory behind this assignment operation?

Thanks...!

Comment: Although functional, convoluted to read. If you are coming here to the community to understand the code (which essentially is a simple conditional statement with a field assignment), I recommend you use the old fashioned `if (snWrap.Prefunded == 'ZEW') serialNumberObj.Prefunded__c = 'ZEW';`

Comment: @TSmith your suggestion seems not right since `Prefunded__c is a boolean field`. Maybe you meant,  `if (snWrap.Prefunded == 'ZEW') serialNumberObj.Prefunded__c=true;` ?

Comment: @Lafexlos good spot, apologies on the typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` 
This is called [Equality operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm). Returns `True` or `False` depending on the equality of its operands. It has [precedence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_precedence.htm) over assignment operator which means it is executed first.

```
serialNumberObj.Prefunded__c = snWrap.Prefunded == 'ZEW';
```

In here, first `snWrap.Prefunded == 'ZEW'` is executed then the result (which is a boolean), assigned to `Prefunded__c` field.